# Changing a variable in an already running function C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am creating my first nacl app and am encountering an issue.

I need to stop a running `while` loop by changing its condition.

My code kind of looks likes this:

```
int flag = 1;     
static void Test1() {
    while (flag) {
        sleep(2); 
    }    
}
```

I want to change `flag` (`flag = 0`) in a safe way by calling another function to stop the infinite loop. How can I do this in C++?

Comment: This is not C++ code.

Comment: Vague question that's answer is too trivial to be the real question...  Code in some mystery language that has nothing to do with C++...  Failure to research on own...  No indication what you're really trying to accomplish...  Do we have an SO bingo winner here?

Comment: `var` shoudl be similar to `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: Change it ... from another thread?  From another function?  What?  There's a ton missing here.

Comment: nacl.. sodium chloride? There are two NaCls,  the salt library and  google native client.. and task looks quit  strange formulated this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use atomic_int for a variable that can be safely changed:

```
std::atomic_int flag = 1;     
static void Test1() {
      while (flag) {
              sleep(2); 
       }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **use a lock** to make sure your writes are safe and won't corrupt the value. You're threading library should provide you with locks. If your application isn't multithreaded, don't even worry about adding in this protection.

An example using the pthread POSIX library (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-6867/sync-12/index.html for a more intricate example):

```
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t g_flag_lock;
int g_flag;

void change_flag(int value) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&g_flag_lock);
    g_flag = value;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_flag_lock);
}
```

Generally speaking, you only need to lock when writing a value. Reading doesn't usually create issues (I can think of one instance in my professional career that I locked on a read because something funky was happening).

Essentially, `pthread_mutex_lock(&g_flag_lock);` checks to make sure no other thread has currently locked `g_flag_lock`. If one has, it waits until that thread unlocks it again, and then snags it for itself.

I should also note that it isn't wise to haphazardly use locks. You'll find yourself in a deadlock situation. When writing multithreaded applications, you really need to think about the architecture and the timing.

I would assume that the `std::atomic` types simply abstract this pattern. I can't say for sure though.

Comment: The question has c++11 tag - you could just use `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`.  (Or, as mentioned, `std::atomic<int>` if that suffices.)

Comment: @Treebacher, the atomic types may abstract the pattern or they may use processor specific instructions through compiler intrinsics. The member `is_lock_free` says whether they use locks.

Comment: @Treebasher - I believe you need atomics to guarantee read coherence outside of the x86/x64 architecture which happens to guarantee that much without even atomics (IIRC)

Comment: @Mordachai if that was so, those never existed https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html (supported on Intel platforms)

Comment: @Mordachai strictly speaking architecture, I believe that the concern primarily comes into play when using values bigger than the native word size of the architecture. So yeah, a 64-bit build for a 64-bit architecture is pretty safe because the native word size is big enough for the majority of types used. From my quick research, ARM and x86 both seem to have some protection for reads in normal cases though. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Treebasher that's my impression as well - but I do all my programming on x86/x64 architecture - so that has never come up for me.  Just my memory from my reading / conferences.  However, worth verifying if you're writing code with that assumption for non Intel hardware. :)

Comment: best to always use atomics or locking to be safe. on x86 with `std::memory_order_acquire` or `std::memory_order_release` it compiles to a simple `mov` instruction and no memory fence instructions, producing the same performance you would get from naive use of reading and writing in a non-atomic fashion.

Comment: (ran out of time to edit, continuing) however, if you can guarantee through some other means, like synchronizing through locks or the process of starting a thread, that you've synchronized with whatever thread wrote last, after it wrote, then you can just use an ordinary read.